# Angular Material Datepicker will not work for me

Tags: angular, angular-material

Im trying to use the date picker. I have no issue with the checkbox or radio buttons. But when I try and add the date picker I always get this error:

> Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'htmlFor' since it isn't a known property of 'md-datepicker-toggle'

in my app.module.ts file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MdButtonModule, 
    MdCheckboxModule,
    MdCardModule,
    MdRadioModule, 
    MdDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WeekControlComponent } from './week-control.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  WeekControlComponent
],
imports: [
   BrowserModule, 
   FormsModule,
   MdButtonModule, 
   MdCheckboxModule, 
   MdCardModule, 
   MdRadioModule,
   MdDatepickerModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And I have a WeekControlComponent:

HTML

```
<input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
<md-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="picker"></md-datepicker-toggle>
<md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
```

TS

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-week-control',
    templateUrl: './week-control.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./week-control.component.css']
  })
  export class WeekControlComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
  }
```

I copied the example straight from the angular.io material examples page. I dont understand why its not working. Can someone please help me here?

Comment: I have a working plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/NWIq75PQM4l7awHLygDq?p=preview) that I made for the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46159653). Maybe it will help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just install latest angular dependencies. i.e.

```
"@angular/animations": "4.3.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
"@angular/common": "4.3.0",
"@angular/compiler": "4.3.0",
"@angular/core": "4.3.0",
"@angular/forms": "4.3.0",
"@angular/http": "4.3.0",
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "4.3.0",
"@angular/router": "4.3.0"

devDependencies:
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.0"
```

And test your code. It works fine for me.

Comment: I was using material "2.0.0-beta.8", when I updated to "2.0.0-beta.10" it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If you using material version 2.0.0-beta.8 then you need to do the following changes:-

1. Replace code in HTML File

   ```
   <md-input-container>
   <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
   <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="picker"></button>
   </md-input-container>
   <md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
   ```

2.Add one more module in app.module i.e. MdNativeDateModule

```
import { MdButtonModule, 
MdCheckboxModule,
MdCardModule,
MdRadioModule, 
MdDatepickerModule, 
MdNativeDateModule   } from '@angular/material';


 imports: [
  BrowserModule, 
FormsModule,
MdButtonModule, 
MdCheckboxModule, 
MdCardModule, 
MdRadioModule,
MdDatepickerModule,
MdNativeDateModule
```

],

Comment: When I tried your code I got and error about the md-input-container not being recognized, using 2.0.0-beta.8. And when I updated to 2.0.0-beta.10 I got an error about the button not having mdDatepickerToggle bindable. But after updating the official example from angular.io started working.

Comment: To make it work in angular material- 2.0.0-beta.8, add " MdInputModule" also.

Comment: For the given material version 2.0.0-beta.8, this is the working solution. This works for anyone stuck to this material version like me. Thanks @Kriti